# How do I change the iCloud ID on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

I lent my iPhone to someone who logged into iCloud with their apple ID. Now I want to change the iCloud account to my own, which can only be done by deleting the currently logged-in iCloud account. To do that, I have to enter the password for that account, to turn off the Find My iPhone app. There seems to be no way to remove the old account without knowing the password for it.

This is on an iPhone 5, with iOS 7.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1) Get the person you lent it to to enter their password and disable their account on your device.

2) Bring proof of ownership (sales receipt) and your device to an Apple Store and talk with a Genius. They will be able to reset the device for you.

Comment: Wife and I have swapped phones.  I can't figure out how to delete her icloud login on the phone, and yes I do have all login info. How do you remove that account entirely from this phone?

Answer (score -1):

That is true. There's NO way you can do this, since iOS 7.